# What is the standard setup for web design agency / creative agencies on Azure Web Apps?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

**Background**

Our company designs and hosts websites for approx. 500 clients, each client has one website. Each website is built on ASP.net. Our current hosting infrastructure is built on hypervisors with virtual machines running Windows. We have 3 virtual machines all running the same spec (8 cores, 24 GB RAM). The 500 client sites are split over these three web servers, there is no load balancing or fault tolerance – the website exists in only one location.

Therefore, as we accumulate clients each web server’s site count increases. When we max out each server, we bring another one online and start again, then once that one is full we spin another VM up etc.

**Goal**

We would like to move (eventually) our sites over to Azure, however we do not want to replicate our current set up on Azure, instead we would like to move each website over to Azure Web app instead to take advantage of scaling.

We would also like more fine-grained control over our costs when bringing online additional sites. Currently, we bring online a VM and costs us X (for an empty server), it may take us 3 months to fill this. We would like to steadily add to our hosting hosts, not in big steps.

**My question**

I have investigated for many days on this and cannot find a tutorial or guide on what the ideal set up looks like on Azure Web apps when hosting 100’s of websites. Almost all tutorials assume you only ever going to have one website, so there is a 1:1 relationship between a site and the underlying resource.  They never talk about how you should organise your apps into App Service Plans etc.

I understand the concept of adding a website, choosing the appropriate pricing tier and setting the scale settings, what I do not understand is why people online talk about scaling out Azure Apps – surely if an ASP.net websites consumes a certain amount of RAM on a system, by bringing online another VM all you are doing is immediately consuming that amount of RAM again on another system. So scaling out in this sense is to ONLY improve availability – is this correct?

If someone is able to provide some of their own experiences when dealing with a lot of websites on Azure (even better if they own a web design company who hosts on Azure) it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Think of AppService plan as a VM or pool of VMs (in case you run multiple instances) that runs the same applications simultaneously and share the same data disc. If you scale out, you add a new VM to the pool, if you scale up, you change the size of VMs (actually they aren't VMs, but from the user's point of view it is simmilar).

So basically in case like yours, where you run many applications (potentially) smaller applications, scaling up/down establishes the baseline - how many websites you can run, how many applications you can fit in the memory. And then scaling out gives your better reliability and more CPU power that helps you to cope with high traffic.

Our company is much smaller than yours, we host dozens of websites not hundreds. But there are some points that our experience have taught us:

- Use at least S2 instances that have 2 cores, with S1 instances a single app can easily degrade performance of other apps in the same AppService plan
- Use TrafficManager. If a need arises (e.g. an outage of the service in your region), you can easily move to another region
- Split webistes between more smaller AppService plans and collocate applications with the similar usage patterns to the AppService plans. That way you can run one instance, when the traffic is low and spin up new instances when the traffic spikes up.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that in all pricing tiers (except free and shared) web apps are scaled to all machines in an app service plan. This is an availability feature from the perspective of a web app. Scaling an app service plan from 1 to 2 machines(or auto-scaling) essentially provisions the same web app on all the machines. This of course is no good for your situation, but all is not lost. Generally, the unit of scaling is the app service plan. You could break down web apps into buckets of app service plans. Say first 100+ web apps in AppServicePlan1, then roll over to the next 100+ in AppServicePlan2. The downside is that you will have to manage tracking what app service plan to place the next web app in.